# My show/hide button bootstrap on my navbar is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, web

When my screen gets small and the toggle button shows while my menu disappears, when clicked it doesn't show my menu. Here is my codes.

```
     <div id="menu" class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button class="btn btn-success navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse collapse"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th-list"></span></button>
        <div id="logo">
        <a href="#"><h3>Zaynee Corals</h3></a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li class="nav active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li class="nav"><a href="about.html">About Us</a></li>
        <li class="nav"><a href="#">Training</a></li>
        <li class="nav"><a href="#">Shop</a></li>
        <li class="nav"><a href="gallery.html">Gallery</a></li>
        <li class="nav"><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
        <li class="nav"><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>        
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably the error is here:

```
data-target=".navbar-collapse collapse"
```

Try change in:

```
data-target=".navbar-collapse.collapse"
```

or:

```
data-target=".navbar-collapse"
```

Comment: Ok, at row <div class="navbar-collapse collapse"> add id="myid" and change data-target in data-target="#myid"